# How can I play music while the screen is locked?

Tags: release-loki, greeter

I have the problem: when I use `Super + L` for screen lock all background activities (f.e. music) freeze. I've tried to change `ligthDM` for `gdm, sddm, cdm, sdm, lxdm` but all of them showed black screen after `Super + L`. So, how to set another DM working properly, or how to fix "freezing problem?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unfixible problem and a technical limitation of the display server (X11). Until we switch to Wayland as the display server, it won't be possible to allow music to continue playing while the screen is locked.

Comment: Can I manually switch to Wayland?

Comment: You said it's impossible to keep music play on X11 on locked screen. Ubuntu uses X11, why it works there?

Comment: @danielleontiev They might be using "late locking" which means they don't actually lock the session until the display gets woken up. There's some questions about if that's really safe or not. Music can't be played while the session is legitimately locked, so if you're playing back music your session is not actually locked.

It's not possible to run Pantheon on Wayland at this time.

Answer (score 0):

The locking / freezing problem depends from your screen locker (`light-locker` in  this case) that starts after you press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. (It seems normal that changing the display manager does not resolve this problem).

You might want to disable screen locking, debug or change light-locker.